# Win 8.1 charms icons off center

Tags: windows-8.1, charms-bar, hot-corner

When I swipe from bottom corner, icons in charms are much lower, than it was on W8.
Swiping from top corner pulls them up. However if I press Win+R, they are in center.

This isn't happening on some lower resolutions.
Is there any way to disable this behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which corner you swipe from or put the mouse into. 
It's to make them easier to reach.
No way that I can see to disable.